# wpf button change image source

Tags: wpf, image, button

I code wpf application. I have a big scheme with many buttons that created and appeared dynamicly. When user click on the buttons, its images have to changed dynamicly too. But I have got a problem: when button image have been changed, the past image stayed on the grid. 
How can I change the button image correctly, or remove image that stayed?

Here is my xaml file:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScroll" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas x:Name="InCanvas"  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=imageMnemoScheme}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=imageMnemoScheme}">
            <Image x:Name="imageMnemoScheme" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/mnemoscheme.bmp" Stretch="None" />
         </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I need ScrollViewer because scheme is a very big.

This is style for buttons that created dynamicly:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is code for creating buttons:

```
    private ImageSource BitmapFromImagePath(string path)
    {
        byte[] imageData;
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
            }
        }
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream(imageData);
        bitmap.StreamSource = st;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
    }

    private void MakeImage(Point pos, int objType, int objState, int objOrientation, int objColor)
    {
        Image xz = new Image();
        xz.Source = BitmapFromImagePath(GetImagePathByType(objType, objState, objOrientation, objColor));
        xz.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Style = style;
        b.Content = xz;
        b.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ObjectImageClick);
        InCanvas.Children.Add(b);
    }
```

This code for deleting past image from button, that stayed on the grid and supperimposed on the new button image:

```
    Image xz = (Image)myB.Content;
    BitmapImage bi = (BitmapImage)xz.Source;
    MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)bi.StreamSource;
    ms.FlushAsync();
    ms.Close();
    ms.Dispose();
    myB.Content = null;
    xz.Source = null;
    bi.StreamSource = null;
    ms = null;
    bi = null;
    xz = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Image smth = new Image();
    smth.Source = BitmapFromImagePath(GetImagePathByType(objType, newObjState, objOrientation, objColor));
    smth.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    myB.Content = smth;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you never remove any button from `InCanvas`, or at least I could find any related code in your question.

You might clear the Canvas before adding a new Button in `MakeImage`:

```
InCanvas.Children.Clear();
InCanvas.Children.Add(b);
```

---

Besides that, your code is much too complicated. Loading an image from file does not require more code than this:

```
private ImageSource BitmapFromImagePath(string path)
{
    return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(path));
}
```

If for some reason you need to read the file manually (e.g. if you want to delete it immediately after reading):

```
private ImageSource BitmapFromImagePath(string path)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(
            fileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

Possibly the safest or easiest way to create an ImageSource from a path string is to use the built-in `TypeConverter` for `ImageSource`:

```
private ImageSource BitmapFromImagePath(string path)
{
    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter();
    return converter.ConvertFrom(path) as ImageSource;
}
```

Your image deletion code is entirely redundant. Remove all this:

```
Image xz = (Image)myB.Content;
BitmapImage bi = (BitmapImage)xz.Source;
MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)bi.StreamSource;
ms.FlushAsync();
ms.Close();
ms.Dispose();
myB.Content = null;
xz.Source = null;
bi.StreamSource = null;
ms = null;
bi = null;
xz = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```